# Correct way to retrain a Keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Once I have trained a Keras model, I save it using:

```
model.save('model.keras')
```

for me to retrain it I import via:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
```

I load the model using:

```
model = load_model('model.keras')
```

and use

```
model.fit()
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Ok, but how to do it without the optimizer states being reset?

Comment: Hi @Marco Yes, it is correct.                                                                                          
If you want to load a Keras model without resetting the optimizer states, you'll need to do some additional steps. By default, when you load a model using load_model(), it will restore the architecture, weights, and optimizer states, which includes resetting the optimizer's state. To load the model without resetting      
1. Save the optimizer along with the model.
2. Load the model and optimizer separately.
3. Compile the loaded model using the loaded optimizer.